# How to set BorderRadius property for div using Script#?

Tags: script#

Something like this:

```
div.Style.BorderRadius = "50%";
```

There is no such property apparantly.

What is the alternative for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since BorderRadius is missing from the Style definition/metadata, there are a few options:

1. Workaround:

   Script.SetField(div.Style, "borderRadius", "...");
2. Fix the piece that is missing:

   Update the code in https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/blob/cc/src/Libraries/Web/Html/Style.cs and submit a pull request.

   Or at the very least, log an issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's supposed to be `.style.borderRadius` (case sensitive), e.g.

```
var x = document.getElementById("example");
x.style.borderRadius = "14px 33px 50px 72px";
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/VtkXG/)

Comment: I want to implement that in Script#

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery bindings:

```
jQuery.FromElement(div).CSS("border-radius", "50%");
```